# Need help to understand how to get only the latest entry from gravity form entry table in wordpress to show in gravity view

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am new to wordpress gravity forms and kit.  I am able to save a form data into the database. I am able to resubmit the same form any number of times which adds to multiple entries for it in the database. I have a view form (gravity view) in the front end website to show the saved data  from the database. As multiple entries for the same form gets created every time i save the form, I want to fetch the latest entry to display in the front end website. Please explain how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a simple MySQL query:

```
global $wpdb; 

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gf_entry_meta';
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY `date_created` DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

[More on the Gravity Forms database structure here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/database-storage-structure-reference/).

Comment: thank you for the reply. but how do i map it in gravity view? The advanced filter do not provide an option to do this. Please provide the steps

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you provide some source code or examples in your original question?