# SQL get last entry of a specific gravity form

Tags: sql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a ROI calculator that needs to show the results as a graph. I am using the [Visualizer Plugin](https://docs.themeisle.com/article/1207-how-to-generate-charts-from-the-database), which allows for chart data to be populated by the db.

I need a SQL query that will get the last entry of a specific form ( id=2), once i have this i should be able to display the chart on the results page after submission.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457906/need-help-to-understand-how-to-get-only-the-latest-entry-from-gravity-form-entry) but it did not work.

```
global $wpdb; 

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gf_entry_meta';
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY `date_created` DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

Comment: can you show what you got and elaborate on *did not work*